# numpy.logical_and explanation in code example

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to reproduce the code from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663764/determine-if-an-image-exists-within-a-larger-image-and-if-so-find-it-using-py), but I get an exception when running the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_image(im, tpl):
    im = np.atleast_3d(im)
    tpl = np.atleast_3d(tpl)
    H, W, D = im.shape[:3]
    h, w = tpl.shape[:2]

    # Integral image and template sum per channel
    sat = im.cumsum(1).cumsum(0)
    tplsum = np.array([tpl[:, :, i].sum() for i in range(D)])

    # Calculate lookup table for all the possible windows
    iA, iB, iC, iD = sat[:-h, :-w], sat[:-h, w:], sat[h:, :-w], sat[h:, w:]
    lookup = iD - iB - iC + iA
    # Possible matches
    np.logical_and(True, False)
    npnd= np.logical_and(*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)])
    possible_match = np.where(npnd)

    # Find exact match
    for y, x in zip(*possible_match):
        if np.all(im[y+1:y+h+1, x+1:x+w+1] == tpl):
            return (y+1, x+1)

    raise Exception("Image not found")

img1 = cv2.imread('c:/temp/1.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('c:/temp/3.png',0)
tplImg = cv2.imread('c:/temp/2.png',0)

find_image(img1, tplImg)
```

The exception happens in this line:

```
npnd= np.logical_and(*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)])
```

And it fails with this exception message:

```
C:\Python36-32>python.exe cvtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cvtest.py", line 33, in <module>
    find_image(img1, tplImg)
  File "cvtest.py", line 19, in find_image
    npnd= np.logical_and(*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)])
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it, to make this code work?

Comment: It's going to be hard to guess what you're doing wrong without an exactly reproducible example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `np.logical_and` takes two arguments (ok, 3 - but you probably don't want to set the `out`-argument!!!), maybe you should check what `len(range(D))` is.

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov you haven't really, though. No one but you has, e.g., C:/temp/1.png on their file system. So you should isolate the array manipulation from the file I/O. In words, remove all parts of the code where you're reading data from disk and generate it manually.

Comment: The code you're copying from is wrong. It misuses `np.logical_and`, and might have other mistakes. Also, it really shouldn't be using so many list comprehensions.

Comment: OK, that code returns `range(0, 1)` (printed with `sys.stdout.write(str(range(D)))`)

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov `len(range(0, 1)) == 1` so that's exactly what I meant. :) (see also my answer).

Comment: Improvement:`tplsum = tpl.sum(axis=(0, 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) takes 2 inputs and one optional `out`-parameter. However due to the call `*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)]` you have `D` arguments. When `D` is 2 everything is ok, when it's 3 you have a Bug and when it's < 2 or > 3 you get the Exception you got.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.logical_and(*[[1]])
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
>>> np.logical_and(*[[1], [2]])
array([ True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_and(*[[1], [2], np.array([1])])
array([1])
>>> np.logical_and(*[[1], [2], np.array([1]), 3])
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

This can be fixed by using `np.logical_and.reduce` which takes an arbitary amount of arrays:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)])
```

Comment: OK, your code is not fails, but... But example code in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663764/determine-if-an-image-exists-within-a-larger-image-and-if-so-find-it-using-py looks like wrong... It can't find images... Pity...

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov I'm sorry I can't really help you with the image detection. I just knew how to fix that particular exception because I regularly run into it. Maybe you could comment on the original answer asking for clarification? :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I asked another question on image searching with OpenCV :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634689/opencv-c-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image

Comment: `[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)]` can be spelt `lookup == tplsum`, right?

Comment: @Eric Probably, I haven't checked possible optimizations mostly because the code wasn't that easy to follow in the first place. For example I haven't checked if `lookup`s last dimension and `tplsum`s dimension are identical and if they equal to `D`. :)